# Android ViewPager scrolling lagging

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager in my app which scrolls 3 Fragments.The problem with it is the scrolling is lagging.First I thought it was because I change the indicators in onPageSelected method.But later found that was not the issue.Below is the code..Waiting for your help..

Code:
ViewpagerActivity.java:

```
binding.viewpager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        binding.viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);

        binding.viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
  }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

PagerAdapter.java:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {

        ArrayList instances;


        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            instances=new ArrayList();
            instances.add(new Frag1());
            instances.add(new Frag2());
            instances.add(new Frag3());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (instances!=null) {
                return instances.size();
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return (Fragment) instances.get(position);
        }

//        @Override
//        public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
//            return false;
//        }
    }
```

Frag1.java:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
        return view;

    }
}
```

Frag2.java:

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Frag3.java:

```
public class Frag3 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag3,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to set  setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)

Comment: It is working .Could you please explain to me why it is smoothly scrolling now

Comment: This retains your fragments and prevents them from recreating, so you dont inflate UI or do some operations when scrolled. Check this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Comment: I think you can use the FragmentStatePagerAdapter
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter